# Forced MVC save to the DB regardless of data annotation failures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have an issue with uploading data into a system.

I need to modify a singular field in a table/class from the data that is being uploaded, however the data annotations that are assigned to the rest of the entites kick in during the save Entity save to the DB, resulting in the following error:

'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

The data is in a very bad way (nulls, bad data) and validation on the entities is required to help clean that up when the user visits the data to modify anything from now on, however I dont want the validation to kick in when the system needs to legitimately modify a field during an upload of data and doesnt care of the state of the rest of the data.

Is there a way to modify the save to force a save to context (Database) without the validation kicking in and erroring out?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/?

Comment: I have been looking on the net and not found a lot, maybe just typing in the wrong search words, but Im a new user to MVC, so not sure what to try to force a change down as this is legacy code I was trying to add the singular field change to.

Comment: Finally found the code I needed:

ctx.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

Now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah and it's simple, just set your context like this:`context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

Have a good day ;)